# wso2 IS - se pierde la conexión del User store

Tags: wso2

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He creado un User Store que apunta a una base de datos Oracle que tiene el mismo esquema de `wso2 is 6.1.0`, y los usuarios se listan de forma correcta, pero de un momento a otro, como pasado 4 horas, se pierde la conexión y la opción de usuarios se queda pensando para mostrar los usuarios, para solucionarlo, tengo reiniciar el `wso2` is y queda solucionado, o la otra opción que es más rápida es pasar el User store creado **Disable** y luego **Enable**, de esta manera se refresca la conexión de este user store y la incidencia se soluciona, pero esto no es lo correcto.

```
WSO2 IS 6.1.0
User Store Manager Class: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-03-14 08:56:00,711] [830f4183-5d47-4928-87ce-8148de7363dc] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService} - Error while getting user count from user store domain : CGR org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.exception.UserStoreCounterException: Error occurred while retrieving user count
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.getUserCountWithClaims(UserStoreCountService.java:212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.countUsers(UserStoreCountService.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:235)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.stub.UserStoreCountServiceStub.countUsers(UserStoreCountServiceStub.java:1980)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserStoreCountClient.countUsers(UserStoreCountClient.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.user.user_002dmgt_jsp._jspService(user_002dmgt_jsp.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:994)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:485)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:781)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:444)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
    at org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.x509Certificate.valve.X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.invoke(X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while executing the SQL SELECT COUNT(UM_USER_NAME) AS RESULT FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:258)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserCountWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10174)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.getUserCountWithClaims(UserStoreCountService.java:204)
        ... 146 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:239)
        ... 148 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor230.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:242)
        ... 150 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while executing the SQL SELECT COUNT(UM_USER_NAME) AS RESULT FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doCountUsersWithClaims(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:3976)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.countUsersWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:6558)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getCountUsers(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10583)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserCountWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10213)
        ... 154 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2067)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getDBConnection(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doCountUsersWithClaims(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:3946)
```

Comment: ¿Siempre tienes datos en esta query: `SELECT COUNT(UM_USER_NAME) AS RESULT FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?` ? ¿Siempre estás enviando el `UM_TENANT_ID` ? Por otro lado, ¿cuántas conexiones concurrentes soporta el server? ¿estás cerrando adecuadamente las conexiones luego de usarlas? Es probable que las dejes abiertas y nuevas conexiones aparezcan hasta que se alcanzó el límite. Finalmente, lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Sí siempre envío todos los datos, y pasa al consumir las apis internas del wso2 IS https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users/